# Why can't Encrypt handle messages bigger than very small?

Tags: cryptography

This

```
keys = GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[];
message = Rasterize[Graphics[Disk[]], RasterSize -> 10];
Encrypt[keys["PrivateKey"], message]
```

generates the error

```
Encrypt::len: Input too long for this encryption method.
```

despite the message having a `ByteCount` of only 4144. Is this some kind of error, or is there a reason why non-tiny messages are infeasible?
(11.1.0, OS X)

Comment: You could try other short messages, to see if the problem is really the length or actually some other feature of what you are trying to encrypt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair` the key size must be longer than the message. So the following works.

```
keys = GenerateAsymmetricKeyPair[Method -> <|"KeySize" -> 5000|>];
message = Rasterize[Graphics[Disk[]], RasterSize -> 10]
Encrypt[keys["PrivateKey"], message]
```

[image: encrypted]

The default for `"KeySize"` is 4096 which is a bit too small for your raster of 4144 bytes.